The point the user is looking at becomes transparent when the screen is shared in VisionOS
When you share an AppleVisionPro screen, a control button appears.
This button follows your gaze and if you point your gaze somewhere, that place becomes semi-transparent

Is there any way to disable this behavior in my volumetric window so that objects in the window do not become semi-transparent when you look while screensharing ?
P.s if the object is a picture or an attachment in RealityView, this behavior is not observed

